# Use R's NeuralNetToolslibrary to Plot the Network Structure of a H2O Deep Neural Network

Tags: r, ggplot2, h2o

I want to be able to use R's NeuralNetTools tools library to plot the network layout of a h2o deep neural network. Below is a sample code that plots the network layout of the model from the neural net package.

```
library(NeuralNetTools)
library(neuralnet)
data(neuraldat)
wts_in <- neuralnet(Y1 ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data = neuraldat, hidden = c(4), 
rep=1)
plotnet(wts_in)
```

I want to do the same thing but use H2o deep neural model. The code shows how to generate a layout by only knowing the number of layers and weight structure.

```
library(NeuralNetTools)
# B1-H11, I1-H11, I2-H11, B1-H12, I1-H12, I2-H12, B2-H21, H11-H21, H12-H21, 
# B2-H22, H11-H22, H12-H22, B3-O1, H21-O1, H22-O1 
wts_in <- c(1.12, 1.49, 0.16, -0.11, -0.19, -0.16, 0.5, 0.2, -0.12, -0.1, 
        0.89, 0.9, 0.56, -0.52, 0.81)
struct <- c(2, 2, 2, 1) # two inputs, two (two nodes each), one output
x_names<-c("No","Yes") #Input Variable Names
y_names<-c("maybe") #Output Variable Names
plotnet(wts_in, struct=struct)
```

Below is the above neuralnet model but I have used H2o to generate it. I’m stumped on how to get the number of layers.

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
neuraldat.hex <- as.h2o(neuraldat)
h2o_neural_model<-h2o.deeplearning(x = 1:4, y = 5,
             training_frame= neuraldat.hex, 
             hidden=c(2,3),
             epochs = 10, 
             model_id = NULL)

 h2o_neural_model@model
```

I can use the weights #h2o.weights(object, matrix_id = 1) and bias function #h2o.biases(object, vector_id = 1) to build the structure but I need it to determine the number layers. I know I can specify the number layers in the model to start with but I sometimes write code that will determine the number of layers going into the model and so I need to a function determine the layers in network structure and weights for the plotnet() function below.

```
  plotnet(wts_in, struct=struct)
```

As an alternative, it would be nice if I had a ggplot2 function instead of the plotnet() function.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps better suited for Data Science: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why can't you just do `length(hidden)`?  I don't understand why you think you don't have that information already, even if `hidden` is created using a function (instead of hardcoded like your example above).

Comment: True, but how do I get the weights from the h2o model in the same form as the neuralnet model output?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been 8 months and it's likely that you've already figured it out. However, I will post my solution for those who run into the same problem.

The importance here resides in the parameter *export_weights_and_biases* of *h2o.deeplearning()*; and the *h2o.weigths(neuralnet)* and *h2o.biases(neuralnet)* functions, which gives the parameters you're looking for.

All that's left is ordering the data.

```
# Load your data
neuraldat.hex <- as.h2o(neuraldat)

h2o_neural_model <- h2o.deeplearning(x = 1:4, y = 5,
         training_frame= neuraldat.hex, 
         hidden = c(2,3),
         epochs = 10, 
         model_id = NULL,
         export_weights_and_biases = T) # notice this parameter!

# for each layer, starting from left hidden layer,
# append bias and weights of each node in layer to
# numeric vector.
wts <- c()
for (l in 1:(length(h2o_neural_model@allparameters$hidden)+1)){
    wts_in <- h2o.weights(h2o_neural_model, l)
    biases <- as.vector(h2o.biases(h2o_neural_model, l))
    for (i in 1:nrow(wts_in)){
        wts <- c(wts, biases[i], as.vector(wts_in[i,]))
    }
}
# generate struct from column 'units' in model_summary
struct <- h2o_neural_model@model$model_summary$units
# plot it
plotnet(wts, struct = struct)
```

The h2o object that it's returned by the deeplearning function it's quite complex and one can get lost in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/h2o/h2o.pdf).